# XPath name() function for an element other than current?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, syntax

Given this XML

```
<some>
    <where>
        <in>
            <hell></hell>
        </in>
    </where>
</some>
```

and this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="in">
    this is a <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    this is a <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::where/name()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the first `value-of` comes back with "in"; the second is a syntax error. I would have expected to see `"where"` but I can't begin to understand the syntax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to using an XSLT 1 processor and XPath 1, in XPath you can't call a function as the last step, that feature was only introduced in XPath 2.

The specs are online so consult https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/ if you want to learn more about the rules of XPath 1, the expression language used in XSLT 1.

Comment: neither xsltproc or xmlstarlet do XPath 2 seemingly. end of the road for that scheme!

Answer (score 2):

XPath 2.0 is required to use a function in the last step of an XPath expression, as Martin Honnen has mentioned.

However, even in XPath 1.0, the [`name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-name) function takes an optional nodeset as an argument.  When unspecified, it defaults to a nodeset with the context node as its only member.  That's why your first example works, and that's how you can get your second example to work:

Change

```
this is a <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::where/name()"/>
```

to

```
this is a <xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::where)"/>
```

or, for the name of the parent node without knowing it a priori:

```
this is a <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
```